# How to make a Horizontal List in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swiftui

I can wrap all my views inside a List

```
List {
   // contents
}
```

But this seems to be vertical scrolling. How do I make it horizontal?

Comment: see https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/building-lists-and-navigation

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You need to add `.horizontal` property to the scrollview. otherwise it won't scroll.

```
ScrollView (.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
     HStack {
         //contents
     }
}.frame(height: 100)
```

Update

```
ScrollView {
    LazyHStack {
         ForEach(arrayOfContent, id: \.id) { item in
              // content
         }
         .listStyle(.plain)
    }
}
```

Comment: That's not a list it renders it all simultaniously

Comment: Check this out - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TU2lR1qAe_k&t=24s

Answer (score 38):

Starting from `iOS 14 beta1` & `XCode 12 beta1` you will be able to wrap `LazyHStack` in a `ScrollView` to create a horizontal lazy list of items, i.e., each item will only be loaded on demand:

```
ScrollView(.horizontal) {
            LazyHStack {
                ForEach(0...50, id: \.self) { index in
                    Text(String(index))
                        .onAppear {
                            print(index)
                        }
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 15):

To make a horizontal scrollable content, you can wrap a `HStack` inside a `ScrollView`:

```
ScrollView {
  HStack {
    ForEach(0..<10) { i in
      Text("Item \(i)")
      Divider()
    }
  }
}
.frame(height: 40)
```

Comment: This would not reuse view-s, so not sure that it is ok solution. Also, i did not see anywhere example of horizontal list, maybe we will need to wait for it a bit :)

Comment: I am not sure that even List properly reuses the items )

Comment: @Markicevic Apple tutorials also use the same approach to make horizontal scroll content and as DenFav said we're not sure about List reusing. However, certainly there will be improvements in the next beta releases!

Comment: Agree that we are not yet sure List is reusing view-s, but not sure how it would be possible for it to not reuse, i mean why have list, we could have Scroll and VStack in it, why then have List. I agree this is correct to have horizontal items on screen, but not sure it will work as List. Still a lot to lear from SwiftUI.

Comment: @Markicevic Maybe it is just a style thing combined with functionality like swipe to delete, which does not make sense in other generic lists. List could therefore be just a specialized VStack ForEach combo. Also SwiftUI has kind of a lazy nature and I could imagine that each view in an ForEach View only gets generated when needed.

Comment: I inspected the hierarchy and it looks like the `List` is built on top of `UITableView`, and it recycles cell as well; the `HStack` within a `ScrollView` doesn't recycle, if you try to debug hierarchy you'll see all view outside the scroll view bounds

Comment: How would you center the element, if the size of the list is just one?

Answer (score 1):

You can use .horizontal property and use custom elements. For me I use cusomt CircleView

```
  var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Divider()
            ScrollView(.horizontal){
                HStack(spacing:10){
                    ForEach(0..<10){
                        index in
                        CircleView(label: "\(index)")
                    }
                }.padding()
            }.frame(height:100)
            Divider()
            Spacer()
        }
        
    }
}

    //struct CircleView:View
    @State var label:String
    var body:some View {
        ZStack{
            Circle()
                .fill(Color.yellow)
                .frame(width: 70, height: 70)
            Text(label)
        }
    }
}
```